# Se puede encriptar por frase en SQL Server 2008 R2?

Tags: sql-server

estoy queriendo encriptar y desencriptar mis contraseñas en una base de datos sql server r2 2008, pero veo segun lo que he investigado que solo se hace por certificados, se podra configurar para que me deje encriptar por frase o mejor instalo una version mas reciente?

Comment: Perdón, ya sé que no viene al caso, pero las contraseñas no se guardan.

Comment: Yo juraría, que se puede desde 2005. [EncryptByPassPhrase](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2019/11/08/encryptbypassphrase-y-decryptbypassphrase-y-no-morir-en-el-intento/)

Comment: Javi fer2, Pues en el sql 2008 r2 lo estoy intentando pero parece que no se puede ya que me devuelve null, o no se si habria que reinsertar todas las contraseñas y talves asi sea posible

Comment: Que te devuelva null no quiere decir, que no se puede, sino que algo no está correcto. Si no se pudiera, la funcion te daría un error. Algún paso te estás saltando en lo que estás intentando hacer. Si necesitas ayuda, tendrás que editar la pregunta y pegar explicitamente todo el código que estás intentando.

Comment: Hola buenos dias, gracias por contestar, solo aclarar que ya lo resolvi, lo que hice fue hacer un update de un usuario, es decir le actualice la contraseña, liuego ya desde el sistema actualice la contraseña de los demas usuarios y ya con eso, no me pregunten como solo se me paso por la cabeza y funciono.... :v